# Where can I find android-v7 support library jar

Tags: android

I want to use the new ActionBarActivitiy class from the v7 support library but I cannot find the support JAR anywhere. I have a v7 folder in my extras directory but it contains 3 directories and not a jar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Eclipse right click on on your *Project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library...* and follow the instructions. As the result, required jar-file gets copied into your project's *libs* folder. Or you can add libraries manually how it is described in [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).

**Update 1:**  Android Tools team has made some changes to the way support library is integrated.

Android updates do this a bit different. There is still Android Tools -> Support Library option, but now it behaves a bit different. Once activated, Eclipse will *silently* create a new project called `appcompat_v7` or similar. The name might change in the next versions of ADT. You must be able to find this project in your workspace. This project contains `android-support-*.jar` file. This is a new library project. In turn, your project receives a dependency on that library project.

You can stay with the updated configuration "as is" and start using compatibility API. Or alternatively, you can copy `android-support-*.jar` files into your project's `lib` folder and remove dependency on `appcompat_v7` library project. Both options will work just fine.

**Update 2:** They change this behavior quite often. Try *Project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library...* first. If it doesn't work, please check out [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library) for more recent information.

**Update 3:** It is really worth to migrate to Android Studio to avoid multiple issues with ATD nowadays.

Comment: no instructions where shown and just andorid-support-v4.jar was installed.

Comment: They slightly changed ADT behaviour. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 8):

`ActionBarActivity` is in an Android library project, not a JAR. There are [instructions in the Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) for how to add an Android library project to your environment and attach it to your application project.

Answer (score 3):

You have to update your Support Library through your SDK and then navigate to the folder where your SDK is located! Then go to : Extras->Google and you will find the Project and the jar included!

Comment: In the newer SDKs, the folder is **extras > android**.