# Add Android Support Library to get access to AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-support-library, intellij-14

Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm a complete noob in developing Android applications.

I'm using IDEA 14 and have a tiny working application (using SDK API 25, targeting Android 4.1.2) where the main activity derives from `Activity`. Now I want it to derive from `AppCompatActivity`, but this class is not found. What package I need to install using the SDK Manager and what changes I need to do in my (**ANT**-, not Gradle-based) IDEA project to use the `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this on your app gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a gradle file.

Comment: you can open Android  SDK folder. navigate to this folder <sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/
 and use jar file

Comment: By the way why you dont want to use Android studio?

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302292/where-can-i-find-android-v7-support-library-jar

Comment: Simply adding as a library dependency to the module is sufficient?

Comment: Hm, there are dozens of .jar files inside `<sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/`, but all seem to just contain javadoc or sources. Which one to choose?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).
Android Studio is basically IntelliJ IDEA with proper Android support.

After that add the Android Support Library to your project in the app build.gradle file

Comment: I'm already using IDEA 14 Ultimate (need it for other development) and don't want to install another instance - the space on my SSD is quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed ElegyD's advice and installed Android Studio (the unpacked .zip isn't THAT large as the usual .exe suggests). Then I've created a sample project with toolbar and menu. After having got this working, I simply applies the changes from my tiny IDEA-project into the new Android Studio-based project. It looks like IDEA 14 is either a little bit outdated regarding Android development or at least not as optimized as Android Studio.